# Java - Vector of binary flags

Tags: java, vector, binary, int

If I'm being told that a specific function will return a vector of binary flags (32-bit int value), what does that mean? Can you give an example that demonstrates that?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: So it returns a vector of 32-bit ints, each being a binary flag, or a single int which represents a vector of binary flags?

Comment: I'd say whoever gave you that spec wasn't being very clear.  That can be interpreted in several ways, including `Vector<Integer>` (unlikely but possible).

Answer (score 1):

A thirty-two bit integer can be viewed as a vector of thirty-two ones and zeroes, and bitwise arithmetic can be used to extract individual bits.

For example, if `FLAG_FOO` is an constant whose value is a power of two — say, `1024` — then `flag_vector & FLAG_FOO != 0` confirms that a specific bit is set. This is because `&` is "bitwise and"; it evaluates to an integer whose bits are one where *both* operands' bits are one, and zero where *either* operand's bits are zero. For example, binary `00100110` `&` binary `10000011` is `00000010`. (Except that you're using thirty-two bit integers, obviously, instead of just eight.)

Conversely, "bitwise or", `|`, can be used to construct such a value; for example, `flag_vector = FLAG_FOO | FLAG_BAR | FLAG_BAZ` would have three bits (flags) set.

This is used, for example, in [the `java.util.regex.Pattern` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), whose static `compile` method is overloaded to take a second argument composed of such flags. `Pattern.compile("a.c", CASE_INSENSITIVE | DOTALL)` creates a pattern based on the string `a.c`, with the "case-insensitive" and "`.`-represents-any-character,-even-newline" options enabled.